# Allowing OpenLDAP users to change their own password

Tags: centos, openldap

I seem to be missing something, I have logged in successfully via LDAP as user cent, however I am not able to change the user "cent" (me) password:

```
[cent@elasticmaster2 ~]$ ldappasswd -H ldap://elasticmaster1.kartikv.com -x -D "cn=cent,ou=Group,dc=kartikv,dc=com" -W -A -S
Old password:
Re-enter old password:
New password:
Re-enter new password:
Enter LDAP Password:
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

Either

1. You mistyped your password, or
2. Your OpenLDAP is misconfigured. There should be an entry something like this:

   ```
   access to attrs=userPassword
       by group/groupOfUniqueNames/uniqueMember="<your LDAP admin group>" write
       by anonymous auth
       by self write
       by * none
   ```

Comment: Regardless of what access control policy is defined, the rootdn is always allowed full rights (i.e. auth, search, compare, read and write) on everything and anything. As a consequence, it's useless (and results in a performance penalty) to explicitly list the rootdn among the <by> clauses. http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html#Introduction

Comment: Thank you EJP, how do I put this in an .ldif file and what command needs to be subsequently run to add this to the db. There is no slapd.conf anymore

Comment: @user5191140 You put it into the configuration: either slapd.conf or the online configuration. Both are still supported, contrary to your last sentence. Which you use is another configuration choice. You can write out the LDIF for this, but it's easier to use an LDAP browser if you're dealing with the online configuration. That way you make fewer mistakes.

Comment: @84104 Good point. I think I got that from a book  but it doesn't make sense.

Comment: [root@elasticmaster1 slapd.d]# cat password.ldif
dn: dc=kartikv,dc=com
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: People
access to attrs=userPassword
        by self write
        by anonymous auth
        by users none
access to * by * read
[root@elasticmaster1 slapd.d]#

Comment: [root@elasticmaster1 slapd.d]# ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f password.ldif
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
ldapadd: invalid format (line 4) entry: "dc=kartikv,dc=com"
[root@elasticmaster1 slapd.d]#